# Janusgraph is doing full table scans for equality queries. Not using indexed backend to get better performance

Tags: janusgraph

I'm running janusgraph server backed by AWS Keyspace and Elasticsearch. The elasticsearch backend is properly configured and the dataload process is able to persist data in elasticsearch as expected.

Janugraph is doing full scans for equality based queries. It is not making use of indexes.

Example:

```
gremlin> g.E().has("edge_id","axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df").profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[edge_id.eq(axxxxxxxx6a1796de...                                          1227.690   100.00
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                   0.087
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                   0.003
  GraphCentricQuery                                                                         1227.421
    \_condition=(edge_id = axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df)
    \_orders=[]
    \_isFitted=false
    \_isOrdered=true
    \_query=[]
    scan                                                                                    1227.316
    \_query=[]
    \_fullscan=true
    \_condition=EDGE
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        1227.690        -
```

When I use `textContains` it does make use of the indices.

```
g.E().has("edge_id",textContains("axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df")).bothV().profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[edge_id.textContains(axxxx.....                     2           2        1934.487   100.00
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                   0.125
  GraphCentricQuery                                                                         1934.234
    \_condition=(edge_id textContains axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df)
    \_orders=[]
    \_isFitted=true
    \_isOrdered=true
    \_query=[(edge_id textContains axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df)]:edge_information
    \_index=edge_information
    \_index_impl=search
    backend-query                                                      2                    1934.207
    \_query=edge_information:[(edge_id textContains axxxxxxxx6a1796de717e9df)]:edge_information
EdgeVertexStep(BOTH)                                                   4           4           0.043     0.00
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        1934.530        -
```

Is there a configuration which controls this behavior?
In my opinion doing full table scans are very in-efficient.

When I run janusgraph locally I do see it makes use of index backend even for equality queries.

Comment: Have you explicitly created any composite indexes using the Management API that support the `has` queries?

Comment: `has` is an exact match and so will use the composite index, not the external one.

Comment: I'm explicitly building mixed index. Something like `mgmt.buildIndex(edgeIndexName, Edge.class).....buildMixedIndex(indexBackendName)`. My queries were timing out . I'm suspecting it is because of full table scans. Is it possible to build both composite and mixed indexes?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. This is what the documentation says "JanusGraph distinguishes between two types of graph indexes: composite and mixed indexes. Composite indexes are very fast and efficient but limited to equality lookups for a particular, previously-defined combination of property keys. Mixed indexes can be used for lookups on any combination of indexed keys and support multiple condition predicates in addition to equality depending on the backing index store." So mixed backend includes equality too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/text-search/#full-text-search. By default, mixed indexes only support full-text search while you want equality matches. You need to use String search or Full text + String search.